# clone partition at same offset?

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning

Maybe i do not need it to be at the same offset but...
I have 2 PCs. I deleted all the partitions on one of them and realize the first partition is to restore the os VERY quickly. I had the partition on the other PC. How do i copy the partition and copy it to the same location so the firmware can launch it correctly and allow me to restore quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command line dd utility from a bootable Linux live CD. It will make a block-level copy of one drive to the other.